# I got an error while compiling ipv6calc-0.93.1 pkg for powerpc

Tags: ipv6

I tried compiling ipv6calc-0.93.1 pkg in LTIB for power-pc, but the process stops with an error (`powerpc-8325-linux-gcc: memcmp.o: No such file or directory`) as shown in the image:

[image]